# Keywords having mixed cases in Charm++

Tags: charm++

In Charm++ some keywords have lower case "ck" (eg: `ckout`,`ckNew`) while other have upper case "Ck" (eg: `CkPrintf`, `CkExit`, `CkArgMsg`). Is this just the syntax or does it have any significance too?
I am new to Charm++ and this is something I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the syntax.

Broadly speaking, things were named in what seemed like the least surprising way (e.g. `ckout` being lowercase to match what `std::cout` looks like, classes like `CkArgMsg` starting with a capital), but there are certainly inconsistencies in how things are named in Charm++. We're (note: I'm one of the Charm++ developers) slowly cleaning up things like this and are adding more C++ish naming schemes (like `ck::*`) to new features we develop, but for now, it's one of Charm++'s idiosyncrasies.